# bcrypt wrong number of arguments error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building authentication APIs using bcrypt(3.1.7), and I keep getting an error "Wrong number of arguments(given 0, expected 1)" for

```
    if user && user.authenticate(create_params[:password])
```

Here is the SessionsController where the error occurred.

```
class Api::V1::SessionsController < Api::V1::BaseController
  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: create_params[:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(create_params[:password])
      self.current_user = user
      render(
        json: Api::V1::SessionSerializer.new(user, root: false).to_json,
        status: 201
      )
    else
      return api_error(status: 401)
    end
  end

  private
  def create_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password)
  end
end
```

And this is the User model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # email, name, encrypted_password, authentication_token, password_digest, ...
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  before_create :generate_authentication_token

  has_secure_password

  def generate_authentication_token
    loop do
      self.authentication_token = SecureRandom.base64(64)
      break unless User.find_by(authentication_token: authentication_token)
    end
  end

  ...

end
```

Comment: May you show error stack info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue before. At that time I used devise and bcrypt simultaneously. Actually, you don't need to use these 2 gems at the same time. You need to use only one - devise or bcrypt.

Comment: What is the best choice? Devise or bcrypt?

Comment: I'm familiar with Devise, and prefer it.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `devise` in your gem file, replace:

`user.authenticate(create_params[:password])`

with

`user.valid_password?(create_params[:password])`.